Unable to start keycloak with preview or scripts features enabled
I have been trying to start my keycloak server with ./bin/kc.sh start --features=preview to allow me add custom javascript polices to my server. but it keeps terminating.

My keycloak is deployed using helm. is there a better way to enable this feature and stop my pod from crashing?
and even when I use kc.sh --feature=preview
the policy does not show 


Even if this is off-topic and should be asked on other sites (for example on serverfault.com): please add all clarification in text form, and not as text hidden in a screenshot

The procedure is correct as the policy will not show immediately when clicked on. However once saved, it will show up in the keycloak console
